# Read Array from another Visual Studio C++ Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, variables

I need a Solution, how to read an Array from another Project in Visual Studio 2010.

I have one program to do the GUI and one program doing the maths. In this maths program, i generate a 2d-array to save the data of some spheres. Due to some errors i can't build one program to access and load both API's. Now i've written two seperate programs(projects) in one projectfolder and need to access the Array.

My first solution has been to generate a file with the values of the array, and read it out by the other program. But as my program needs to be fast, max. 20ms per iteration, i don't think this will help me much.

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

I solved my problem... I happen to get my program run in just one application. My mistake has been to call the MatLab-Engine within the main function of NXOpen instead of an own function. Thank you anyway for motivate me to find an "one-program-solution" :)

Comment: Designing your own communication protocols is just asking for trouble, because you have to deal with all the hazards of concurrency. While a decent approach would be to just use a (in-memory) database like SQLite, wouldn't it  be easier to just fix the errors that you are receiving and to do things sequentially in a single application? By the way, what errors are you receiving and could you also provide some relevant code for them?

Comment: Since the program simply shuts down after executing the application i don't know how to handle the problem.
I use the MatLab-Engine and a CAD-Program called Siemens NX8.0, more exactly the NXOpen API. The programs on their own are working perfect but as soon as is added all librarys and includes from the MatLab-Engine to the CAD application and start the application it just shuts down as soon as the MatLab-Engine starts.
So I don't really know how to handle this and needed an alternative.

Comment: Interesting. Does the [Event Log](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer) give any clues? Applications rarely die without reason, especially such high-profile ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share data between multiple processes, you can use file mapping. Check [Sharing Files and Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and here's good example: [Creating Named Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Although dividing your solution into two applications doesn't seem to be right. Before you make your solution even more complicated, try to check first whether there is a way how to make it simple again.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this one. I really tried hard to find a way to do this in one application, but I'm out of ideas to solve it.